# Query CSV file based on a column value using Power Shell

Tags: powershell

I have this `C:\test.csv` file:-

[image]

and i am importing this file and read the data as follow:-

```
$SourceID = @()
$DestinationID = @()

Import-Csv C:\test.csv |`
    ForEach-Object {
        $SourceID += $_.SourceID
        $DestinationID += $_."DestinationID"
    }
```

but how i can query the .CSV file based on the source ID? for example to get the DestinationID for the SourceID = 1?

Thanks

Comment: Changing `ForEach-Object` to `Where-Object { $_.SourceId -eq 1 }` should be it

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon so i will need to Import-Csv each time i need to do the query ? or i can do the Import-Csv once and do multiple queries ?

Comment: you can store the object produced from CSV parsing in a variable and then just query that variable -> `$csv | Where-Object ...`

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon can you provide more code please? so i do not miss what you are referring to ?

Comment: You don't need the continuation mark after the pipe.  I would make a hash table.  `Import-Csv test.csv | foreach-object { $hash = @{} } { $hash[$_.sourceid] = $_.destinationid }`

Comment: @js2010 can you post the full code, as i am confused

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon can you post the full code as i am confused

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would make a hash table.  The first script block is a 'begin' clause.  This can be a good time saver with a large file.  $hash[1] doesn't work.

```
Import-Csv c:\test.csv |
  foreach-object { $hash = @{} } { $hash[$_.sourceid] = $_.destinationid }


$hash['1']
 
10


$hash['2']

20


$hash.gettype()

IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType
-------- -------- ----                                     --------
True     True     Hashtable                                System.Object
```

Comment: can you please check my other  question based on your reply https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73884847/unable-to-get-the-hash-value-for-csv-file-inside-my-power-shell ?