# Unable to get the hash value for CSV file inside my power shell

Tags: powershell, hash, azure-powershell, powershell-4.0

I have this CSV file, and i want to build a hash table for it and query its values:-

[image]

I wrote this powershell script, to read data from sharepoint list and from the csv file:-

```
Connect-PnPOnline -Url "https://**.sharepoint.com" -UseWebLogin
$SourceID = @()
$DestinationID = @()

Import-Csv c:\test.csv |
  foreach-object { $hash = @{} } { $hash[$_.sourceid] = $_.destinationid }
    


for($ii=1; $ii -lt 4;$ii++){


$ListItem = Get-PnPListItem -List "InvoiceDetails" -Id $ii -Fields "InvoiceNumber"    

 foreach($item in $ListItem){

$n = "'"+$item["InvoiceNumber"]+"'"
$n
$hash['1']
$hash[$n]
$hash['+$n+']
}
}
```

now i am getting weird results:-

`$n` will return correct value from SharePoint such as '1', '2', etc..

`hash['1']` will return correct value of 10 from the csv file

while combining both values such as `$hash[$n]` or `$hash['+$n+']` will not return any thing.. any advice?

Comment: I think once you add the values to the hashtable you do this as INT ($hash[$_.sourceid] = $_.destinationid ) and later you try to access those keys by specifing strings. this $hash['+$n+'] requires a key of: +$n+, e.g.: ```$x = @{1,"ssss"};$x[1] gives 1  but $x['1']``` gives you nothing back.

Comment: @Toni more info please?

Comment: ok...give me some minutes

Comment: If ```$n``` is e.g. the literal string ```'1'``` (e.g. assigned by ```$n = "'" + "1" + "'"```) then with ```$hash[$n]``` you're looking for a key called literally ```'1'``` (i.e. 3 characters). The same with ```$hash['+$n+']``` - it's looking for a key called ```+1+```. Neither of those exist in your hashtable.

Comment: @Toni but in my case `hash['1'] ` will return a value while `hash[1] ` will return nothing

Comment: @mclayton but even `$hash[$item["InvoiceNumber"]]` will return nothing~~

Comment: Can you show the output from ```$item["InvoiceNumber"] | ConvertTo-Json``` so we can see the datatype and contents of the variable? ```@{ "1" = "aaa" }[1]``` will return ```$null``` for example, but ```@{ "1" = "aaa" }["1"]``` will return ```aaa``` because the datatype is important - a csv import only contains strings, even if the source data is numbers...

Comment: @mclayton i got 1 2 3

Comment: Ok, and ```$item["InvoiceNumber"].GetType().FullName```?

Comment: @mclayton system.double

Comment: Something doesn't match up there. ```1 2 3```  is not a ```system.double```... In any case, your hashtable keys are ```string```s even though your source csv data contains numbers because ```Import-Csv``` converts everything to strings, so you need to make sure ```$n``` contains a ```string``` for it to find the items by key...

Comment: @mclayton so what need to be done then?

Comment: @mclayton `=$hash[$item["InvoiceNumber"].ToString()]` seems to solve the issue .. thanks for the hint